# Convert ISO date format to moment date format

Tags: angular-material, momentjs

In angular material, used ***mat-datepicker*** for showing date picker.

I need to show custom date formatter in that date field.For custom date formatter, I have used `material-moment-adpator`. But I have ISO date format like this `dd-MM-yyy`. If use this date format, I get `Tu-01-1990` output but I need to get a `10-01-1990`.

How to convert iso date format to moment date format?

Answer (score 0):

for "numeric" days, you should  use DD instead of dd